# deploying war file in tomcat through command prompt

Tags: tomcat, war, web-deployment

can anyone please tell me how to deploy a war in tomcat through command prompt.
i'm using windows as OS.

i've deployed war using gui but don't know how to do that through command prompt.

Comment: You could also use a build tool to automate that process. Take a look at ant, maven, gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just as simple as

```
copy <your-war> %CATALINA_HOME%\<appBase>
```

and make sure `autoDeploy` is true in the `Host` element in the `server.xml` config file. By default it is `true`. `appBase` is also an attribute of the  `Host`  element and is per default `webapps`.

This assumes that you can access  using the filesystem. Otherwise you have to use a tool like [Ant](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AntDeploy) or [Maven](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/context-goals.html)

**EDIT**

```
@ECHO OFF
REM deploy.bat
SET CATALINA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42"
copy /Y %1 %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps
```

copy paste the above code to a file `deploy.bat`, set `CATALINA_HOME` to the installation directory of your tomcat, save and call it in a command prompt like like this:

```
deploy.bat my_webapp.war
```

Comment: sir i'm getting------> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: @user2040500 what command did you exactly type? Is %CATALINA_HOME% defined as environment variable?

Comment: nope how to do that.........what should be the variable name...is it %CATALINA_HOME%  or simply CATALINA_HOME and what about the value name